# How to improve code and missing Records using Thread Task

Tags: c#

I am parsing Database table records and modifying/Type changing(for example in model class Field type is JObject but in DB table is string) according to model class and then finally generating list of JObject.

-Getting the all records from DB:

`List<Dictionary<string, object>>` objectList

-Parsing and generating List of JObject using task(Result).

```
 ConcurrentBag<JObject> parsedObjectList
```

Here is the code:

```
public async Task<string> DBDataParser(){
    var employeeInstance = new Employee();
    var tableName="Emp";

    List<Dictionary<string, object>> objectList = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

    //sql connection
    ..
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
        Dictionary<string, object> dicObject =Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).ToDictionary(reader.GetName, reader.GetValue);
            objectList.Add(dicObject);
        }
    }

    ConcurrentBag<JObject> parsedObjectList = new ConcurrentBag<JObject>();
    try
    {   
        var tasks = new ConcurrentBag<Task>();
        foreach (var dictObject in objectList)
        {
            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async (object entity) =>
             {
                 JObject obj = new JObject();           
                 Dictionary<string, object> data = (Dictionary<string, object>)entity;
                 foreach (var readerObject in data)
                 {

                     var key = readerObject.Key;
                     var column = readerObject.Value.ToString();
                     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(column))
                     {
                       CheckPropertyIsObjectorArrayOrDefault(column, key, tableName, employeeInstance, obj);
                     }               
                 }
               parsedObjectList.Add(obj);
             }, state: dictObject);
            tasks.Add(task);
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return "Success";
}

public async Task<string> CheckPropertyIsObjectorArrayOrDefault(string column, string key, string tableName, Employee tempInstance, JObject obj)
{
    var propertyInfo = tempInstance.GetType().GetProperty(key);
    var typeName = checkNullable(propertyInfo, key, tableName);

    if ((column.StartsWith("{") && column.EndsWith("}")))//For object
    {
        if(typeName.ToLower()!="string")
            obj[key] = JObject.Parse(column.ToString());
        else
            obj[key] = column.ToString();

    }
    else if (column.StartsWith("[") && column.EndsWith("]"))
    {
        if (typeName.ToLower() != "string")
            obj[key] = JArray.Parse(column);
        else
            obj[key] = column.ToString();

    }
    else
    {
        if (typeName != "")
        {
            try
            {
                switch (typeName.ToLower())
                {
                    case "datetime":
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(column))
                        {
                            DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.Parse(column);
                            var convertedDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(convertedDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);
                            obj[key] = convertedDateTime;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "double":
                        obj[key] = Convert.ToDouble(column);
                        break;
                    case "float":
                        obj[key] = Convert.ToDouble(column);
                        break;
                    case "int":
                        obj[key] = Convert.ToInt32(column);
                        break;
                    case "integer":
                        obj[key] = Convert.ToInt32(column);
                        break;
                    case "boolean":
                        obj[key] = Convert.ToBoolean(column);
                        break;
                    case "bool":
                        obj[key] = Convert.ToBoolean(column);
                        break;
                    default:
                        obj[key] = column;
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Debug("Type mismatch ,for type "+ key+ " for the class " + tableName);
            }
        }
        else
        {
           // _logger.Debug("No definition found for the field: " + key + " in the class " + tableName);
        }
    }
}

public static string checkNullable(PropertyInfo prop, string columnName, string tableName)
{
    try
    {
        if (prop != null)
        {
            var nullableType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType);
            bool isNullableType = nullableType != null;
            if (isNullableType)
            {
                return nullableType.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                return prop.PropertyType.Name;
            }
        }
        else
        {
           return "";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    return "";
}
```

I am not throwing any Exception because some of reader object(column/field) data might be null or other reason not presend correctly so that why simply skipping but sure all fields of the tables row not incorrect.

Please give me performance related suggestion if any code need to modify and why not getting count equals for both list `List<Dictionary<string, object>> objectList`
and

```
ConcurrentBag<JObject> parsedObjectList.
```

Thanks.

Comment: I would wrap the task body in try/catch and log any exceptions occurred, it may help to understand the difference in item count.

Comment: Why is `CheckPropertyIsObjectorArrayOrDefault` marked `async`? Same question for the delegate passed to `StartNew`.